# Angular6 array is not getting stored

Tags: javascript, angular, multidimensional-array

From last couple of hours, I'm trying to set simple array but somehow its not happening.

```
messages : [{message: string, nickname: string, user_id: string, profile_url: string, created_at: string, type: string}];

loadMessages(channelUrl){
  this.getChannel(channelUrl)
    .then(channel => {
      this.channel = channel;
      this.getMessageList(this.channel)
      .then(messageList => {
          this.messageList = messageList;
          console.log(this.messageList);
          this.messageList.forEach((messageData)=>{
            console.log(messageData.message);
            this.messages.push({message: messageData.message, nickname: '', user_id: '', profile_url: '', created_at: '', type: ''});
            console.log(this.messages);
          });
        })
      .catch(error => {
        return error.message;
      });
    })

}
```

last console.log is not getting printed. neither its giving any errors.

Please guide.

Comment: Welcome. Please show the result of your first `console.log` (or even first two).

Comment: Hello. you have a `catch` returning the error message but you don't do anything with that. You should at least log the error...or remove it to let it crash and get the error.

Comment: Thanks Jeto & Champagne for your reply.
Jeto - response is coming properly, I cannot print as its big.for second its coming as "test message"

Champagne - Thanks man - I completely forgotten that bit.I'll check it now

Comment: Champagne - _this.messages is undefined - This is coming.
And I'm not sure how can I fix this. :(

Comment: Hi @BhaveshNS you should debug this using dev tools my friend, that way you will have a better understanding of what's going on.

Comment: Thanks. And I know why this is coming and did coding accordingly. Problem what I understood is in typescript if you calling nested function then scope limits to that function.But its not getting fixed

Comment: Hi Champagne, I solved my problem based on your reply. So if you can add that as answer, I can accept it,

Comment: you has a type error (you forget any[]=), is messages : **any[]=** [......]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Champagne has helped me to find the solution. I have added try catch because of that error was not getting displayed.

```
this.messages
```

was undefined